# Optimize query for intersection of ST_Buffer layer in PostGIS

Tags: postgresql, postgis, intersection

I have two tables stored in PostGIS:
1. a multipolygon vector with about 590000 rows (layerA) and 
2. a single multipart (1 row) vector layer (layerB)

and I want to find the area of the intersection between each polygon's buffer in layerA and layerB. My query so far is

```
SELECT ST_Area(ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom)) AS myarea, a.gid AS mygid FROM 
(SELECT ST_Buffer(geom, 500) AS geom, gid FROM layerA) AS a, 
layerB AS b
```

So far, I can see my query working but I calculate that it needs 17 hours to be completed (with my PC). Is there another way to execute this query more efficiently and faster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What if you check intersects of overlapping area before intersection and area calculation, it might lower time.

```
SELECT ST_Area(ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom)) AS myarea, a.gid AS mygid FROM 
(SELECT ST_Buffer(geom, 500) AS geom, gid FROM layerA) AS a, 
layerB AS b WHERE ST_intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
```

Comment: Since no other answer was offered and yours does decrease query time,  I accept it and thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You would probably get more answers to this at [gis.stackexchange.com](https://gis.stackexchange.com/).

Therea are several things you can do.

You should make sure you get that first filtering of polygons actually intersecting with help of index.

Put a gist index on the table with many geometries and use [st_dwithin](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.4/ST_DWithin.html)(geom,500) instead of st_intersects on the buffered geometries. That is because the buffered geometries cannot use the index calculated on the unbuffered geometries.

Also, you say you have multi polygons. If there actually is more than 1 polygon in each multipolygon you might get a lot more speed if you first split the polygons to single polygons before building the index. That will make the.index doing a much bigger part of the job.

There is actually a function in postgis to split even single polygons into smaller pieces for the same reason.
[ST_SubDivide](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.4/ST_Subdivide.html)

So first use [ST_Dump](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.4/ST_Dump.html) to get single polygons:

```
CREATE table a_singles AS 
SELECT id, (ST_Dump(geom)).geom geom FROM a;
```

Then create index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_a_s_geom 
ON a_singles 
USING gist(geom);
```

At last the query, something like

```
SELECT ST_Area(ST_Intersection(ST_Buffer(a_s.geom,500), b.geom)) 
FROM a_singles AS a_s 
INNER JOIN b 
on ST_DWithin(a_s.geom,b.geom,500);
```

If that still is slow you can start playing with ST_SubDivide.

One more thing. If the single multipolygon in table b contains many geometries, also split them and put an index also there.

It might be slow also after all those things. That depends on how many vertex points there is in the splitted polygons that actually intersect (and for st_dwithin also on how many vertexpoints there is in polygons with overlapping bounding boxes)

But now you don't have any index helping you so this should  make it quite a lot faster.